# Does the SES email quota apply to verification mail by Amazon Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

I'm setting up Amazon Cognito user pools as means to authenticate my users.
Cognito sends verification emails (password reset, confirm email address etc.).
Cognito uses Amazon SES for sending emails and Amazon SES is limited to 200 daily email quota per day.
I'm afraid that once I've imported all my users to Amazon Cognito, resulting with each of them receiving a couple of emails upon their next login, I'll be well over the quota and they will not be able to receive those emails.
Does anyone know whether this quota applies to automatic emails by Amazon Cognito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito has gotten a much higher sending limit than 200, you shouldn't run into issues. If you do, feel free to reach out to us via the forums/support and we can get you around that.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Amazon SES for sending emails the certainly Amazon SES quota applies.
But 200 per day sounds suspiciously like SES Sandbox. In which case you're not only limited to 200 a day, but you also have to "validate" each e-mail address first before you can even start sending e-mails to that address.

So, if you want to send large number of e-mails to a wide audience as you described in the question you certainly need to move it out of sandbox.

Just  test your configuration in Sandbox (so you know it's all working correctly) and then apply for quota increase. (I know, it sounds scary, but procedure is actually quite simple and straight forward.)